# Kettle: Want to map string value to id from another table

Tags: mysql, dictionary, mapping, kettle, spoon

I want to map a string from table1 that has this structure:

```
                          Table1
                             id
                             value[string] (this can be repeated)
```

To Table2:

```
                          Table2
                             id
                             value_id
```

So there's another table3 i created, where i have all different values from table1.

```
                          Table3
                             id
                             value(this is unique)
```

So, the intention of this mapping, is to set a value_id instead of the value, so the question is, how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sure, for example: 
    Person 
     id: 1 
     school: 'School of SF' 
    Person 
     id: 2 
     school: 'School of Washington'
    Person
     id: 3 
     school:'School of SF' 
So we want to migrate schools to a table: 

    school 
     id: 1 
     name: 'School of SF'
    school:
     id: 2 
     name: 'School of Washington'
to a new Table on a new DB: 

    newPerson 
     id: 1 
     school_id: 1
    newPerson 
     id: 2 
     school_id: 2
    newPerson 
     id: 3 
     school_id: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a transformation as this:
'Table input' -> 'Database lookup' -> 'Table output'

**Table input**

select person_id, school_name from Table1

**Database lookup**

- Lookup table: Table2
- The keys to lookup the values: school_name = school_name
- Values to return from the lookup table: school_id

**Table output**

- Target table: Table3
- Database fields: person_id, school_id